# How to simplify if/else code if I have a common pattern

Tags: powershell, powershell-5.0

From how I understand it, I am not looking for an if statement, or an elseif statement. In a foreach statement, I am trying to check X, and do one thing, check Y, and do that too, check Z, and do something different for that too.

Here is my current code:

```
    #5 | Add-UserToGrp and adding each user in their OUs to their respective Groups
Function Add-UserToGrp
{
    $OUusers = Import-Csv -Path "C:\MyScripts\FinalProject\csv\createUsers.csv"

    foreach($OU in $OUusers)
    {
        $user   = $OU.OUName
        $oupath = $OU.OUPath

        if($oupath -eq "Sales_OU")
        {
            Add-ADGroupMember -Identity "CN=SalesGrp,CN=Users,DC=PT,DC=LOCAL" -Members "CN=$user,OU=SalesOU,DC=PT,DC=LOCAL"
        }
        if($oupath -eq "HR_OU")
        {
            Add-ADGroupMember -Identity "CN=HRGrp,CN=Users,DC=PT,DC=LOCAL" -Members "CN=$user,OU=HR_OU,DC=PT,DC=LOCAL"
        }
    }
```

Is there some magical statement that will do what I want? I saw something about foreach -parallel that maybe was what I wanted, but it has to be in a workflow and I don't think that's the right direction to go. I need to run like 10 of these if statements and execute code after all of them, within a foreach statement.

Please tell me if I did a poor job explaining or you need me to clarify anything. Thanks in advance for your assistance.

Comment: Are you sure you didn't mean `if($oupath -eq "SalesOU"`...?

Comment: Yup, absolutely positive. See:

$oupath = $OU.OUPath

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming all possible values of your OUPath are in the same format, this will simplify your logic without the if/else structure. You had the basics right before, aside from the typo.

```
Function Add-UserToGrp
{
    $OUusers = Import-Csv -Path "C:\MyScripts\FinalProject\csv\createUsers.csv"

    foreach($OU in $OUusers)
    {
        $user   = $OU.OUName
        $oupath = $OU.OUPath

        # Get everything before OU in $path, with an optional _ between the first part and the OU.  HR_OU becomes HR.  SomethingElseOU becomes SomethingElse.
        $null = ($oupath -imatch "([^_]+)_?OU")
        $path = $matches[1]

        # this combines the $path part into a combined string with the Grp. HR becomes HRGrp.  Sales becomes SalesGrp.
        Add-ADGroupMember -Identity "CN=$($path)Grp,CN=Users,DC=PT,DC=LOCAL" -Members "CN=$user,OU=$oupath,DC=PT,DC=LOCAL"
    }
```

Comment: @Matthew_Wetmore I got some errors.

When I set $null = ($oupath -match "(.*)_OU"), it adds a ton of users that don't belong into the ITGrp & HRGrp, and it leaves all the other groups w/o users.

When I set $null = ($oupath -match "(.*)OU"), without the underscore like I would of thought correct, it adds all of the correct users to the correct OUs, *except* for the ITGrp & HRGrp groups (on account of the underscore missing, I suppose).

Both ways generate a fair number of errors (all of them "Directory object not found"). I'm not really sure how to make PS happy, can you help?

Comment: I think I see the problem. "(.*)_OU" only works for the ITGrp & HRGrp because it has the underscore and it gets dragged into the Add-ADGroupMember correctly. "(.*)OU") works for everything except those two groups because an underscore is being dragged into the Add-ADGroupMember (meaning: -identity "cn=$IT_Grp..."). I don't see a solution to this though. How do I avoid dragging an underscore into the Add cmdlet at the bottom, but still include IT_OU and HR_OU in the -match statement?

Comment: Edited the example above - see the changed -imatch statement. You can try this out at: https://regex101.com/ to learn more about capture groups and play with the format.   Entering `"([^_]+)_?OU` in the regular expression section, then example strings will show what's captured vs. matching the overall string.   This specific match basically says:  capture everything that's not an underscore, up til an optional underscore followed by OU.  You should add more error checking to ensure something actually got matched.

Comment: Works perfectly. I had an error earlier that I fixed that was causing a lot of bleeding. I appreciate the link too, it helped a lot actually. When I first saw the new match statement my eyes glazed over, but regex was surprisingly helpful. It didn't explain -imatch though, or rather, I didn't understand it. How is -imatch different?

Comment: Imatch, and match are both case insensitive, but imatch makes it explicit.  Cmatch is case sensitive.